# SQL SUM by certain values over multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I do have a question about SQL. I have de following table:

```
     d        x      y          p
 2002-09-05  8.0     8       100.00
 2002-09-06  4.0     24      16.66
 2002-09-09  4.0     8       50.00
 2002-09-10  4.0     8       50.00
 2002-09-11  8.0     8       100.00
 2002-09-12  8.0     8       100.00
```

I want to sum the `x` and `y` if `p` is the same and the `d` is one off. The table below is the result i would like to see.

```
      d1        d2        x      y      p
 2002-09-05 2002-09-05   8.0     8    100.00
 2002-09-06 2002-09-06   4.0     24   16.66
 2002-09-09 2002-09-10   8.0     16   50.00
 2002-09-11 2002-09-12   16.0    16   100.00
```

What i have done so far:
I have done this:

```
CTE AS 
(SELECT DATEADD(d, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY percentage ORDER BY d), d) AS group
, * FROM table)
```

And then selected this. But this aint working.

```
SELECT MIN(d) d
,      MAX(d) d1
,      SUM(x) as x
,      SUM(y) as y
,      MAX(p) as p 
FROM   CTE 
GROUP BY group
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(d date, x decimal(18,9), y decimal(18,9), p decimal(18,9))

insert into #temp values
({d '2002-09-05'}, 8, 8, 100),
({d '2002-09-06'}, 4, 24, 16.66),
({d '2002-09-09'}, 4, 8, 50),
({d '2002-09-10'}, 4, 8, 50),
({d '2002-09-11'}, 8, 8, 100),
({d '2002-09-12'}, 8, 8, 100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution does not use a while loop and may better fit your needs

```
SELECT MIN(d) AS d1, MAX(d) AS d2, SUM(x) AS x, SUM(y) AS y, p 
FROM (
    SELECT d,x,y,p,
       DATEADD(dd, - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY p ORDER BY d), d) AS val
    FROM CTE
)t  
GROUP BY val, p
ORDER BY d1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written this script, using a cursor, because you must evaluate every single row respect your output table

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #app (d date, x decimal(18,9), y decimal(18,9), p decimal(18,9))

insert into #app values
({d '2002-09-05'}, 8, 8, 100),
({d '2002-09-06'}, 4, 24, 16.66),
({d '2002-09-09'}, 4, 8, 50),
({d '2002-09-10'}, 4, 8, 50),
({d '2002-09-11'}, 8, 8, 100),
({d '2002-09-12'}, 8, 8, 100)

create table #out (d1 date, d2 date, x decimal(18,9), y decimal(18,9), p decimal(18,9))

declare @d date
declare @x decimal(18,9)
declare @y decimal(18,9)
declare @p decimal(18,9)

declare #crs insensitive cursor for
select d, x, y, p
from #app
order by d, p
for read only
open #crs
fetch next from #crs into @d, @x, @y, @p
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    if (select COUNT(*) from #out where p = @p) = 0
    begin
        insert into #out values (@d, @d, @x, @y, @p)
    end
    else 
    begin
        if (select COUNT(*) from #out where (d1 = @d or d2 = @d) and p = @p) > 0
        begin
            update #out set x = x + @x, y = y + @y where (d1 = @d or d2 = @d) and p = @p
        end
        else if (select COUNT(*) from #out where d2 = dateadd(day, -1, @d) and p = @p) > 0
        begin
            update #out set x = x + @x, y = y + @y, d2 = @d where d2 = dateadd(day, -1, @d) and p = @p
        end
        else 
        begin
            insert into #out values (@d, @d, @x, @y, @p)
        end
    end
    fetch next from #crs into @d, @x, @y, @p
end
close #crs
deallocate #crs

select * from #out order by d1
```

Comment: I really appreciate your input. But i can't use the while statement. This query is going to be in an report.

Comment: @Ocirina: In report you must use only the final date. If you encapsule this script in a stored procedure, you can run it and then pass your data to your report.